# Javascript reduce function use in multiple child array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to count value **count** if common === true under multiple child array but i am not succeed
how to use java script reduce function for get total 4

total sum should be 4 because only 4 object has common === true

```
const obj = {
  "A": [
    [
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": false
      },{
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": true
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": false
      },
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "B": [
    [
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": false
      },{
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": true
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": false
      },
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": true
      }
    ]
  ]
};

let total = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value.reduce((a,b) => a+b.reduce((c,d) => c + (d.common) ? parseInt(d.count) : 0,0),0), 0);
```

Comment: do you have a special reason for numbers as strings? would you add this values or just count the ooccurences?

Comment: @NinaScholz no i use parsInt for this convert to int i just need to count total if common === true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested arrays as values of the object, you need two inner loops to get the wanted properties for summing

```js
const
    obj = { A: [[{ count: "1.00", common: false }, { count: "1.00", common: true }], [{ count: "1.00", common: false }, { count: "1.00", common: true }]], B: [[{ count: "1.00", common: false }, { count: "1.00", common: true }], [{ count: "1.00", common: false }, { count: "1.00", common: true }]] },
    total = Object
        .values(obj)
        .reduce((r, outer) => {
            outer.forEach(inner =>
                inner.forEach(({ common, count }) => r += common ? +count : 0)
            );
            return r;
        }, 0);

console.log(total); // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```js
const obj = {
  "A": [
    [
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": false
      },{
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": true
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": false
      },
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "B": [
    [
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": false
      },{
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": true
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": false
      },
      {
        "count": "1.00",
        "common": true
      }
    ]
  ]
};

let total = 0;
Object.values(obj).forEach(c => c.forEach(arr => total += arr.filter(o => o.common).length));
console.log("Total: " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would to flatten the array using `concat` and then apply `reduce`:

```js
const obj = {
  "A": [
    [{"count": "1.00", "common": false}, {"count": "1.00", "common": true}],
    [{"count": "1.00", "common": false}, {"count": "1.00", "common": true}]
  ],
  "B": [
    [{"count": "1.00", "common": false}, {"count": "1.00", "common": true}],
    [{"count": "1.00", "common": false}, {"count": "1.00", "common": true}]
  ]
};

const sum = [].concat(...([].concat(...Object.values(obj))))
  .reduce(( acc, cur ) => acc + (cur.common ? +cur.count : 0), 0)

console.log(`Total count = ${sum}`);
```